# How to count a large number of files in a directory

Tags: laravel, apache, php-7

I am trying to generate and count large amount of small json files at once (like millions of them) using Laravel's Storage class.

I've tried `count(Storage::files(PATH))` but that did not work due to the fact that there are millions of them.

First it returned an error of execution time being exceeded 30 secs so I have tried upping the `max_execution_time` but now after running for a while it returns a blank page with no clue what went wrong

I am hoping for some kind of clever approach to count all files effectively
maybe as chuncks  (which i dont think storage have as a function)
 or any kind of optimization to the process which might help stopping it from crashing

any help please?

Comment: Why not store a file-counter in the Database, and increment during file generation?

Comment: @levi the number of files will change a lot and i need to keep a 'real-time' counting method for the files so whenever they change the counter will increase or decrease accordingly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this with `PHP`'s `exec` --   Your OS already knows the number of files in the directory .. It indexes it, so why not use it?  Super fast and clean.

```
<?php

exec('ls -l /path/to/your/json/files | grep ^- | wc -l', $out);
echo $out[0];
```

**Note** that this `exec` returns an array -- So you need to use the index of 0 on `$out`

**UPDATE**  -- I tested using the following to create 3,000,000 files --  The resulting php `exec` function ran in < 20 seconds.

```
#!/bin/bash
max=3000000
for i in `seq 2 $max`
do
    echo "$i" > $i.json
    echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: Thank You! that's exactly the kind of approach i'm looking for
the question is how to make it count recursively for files within subfolders?

Comment: i used the -R flag and it did the trick!
thanks man you're a life saver

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Even if you increase `max_execution_time` to 1 hour it will certainly time out anytime around 10 minutes, that's why you are getting a blank page.

@Zak's solution is your best bet.